# Is there a limit to the number of docker volumes one can attach to a container?

Tags: docker

I was wondering if there is a limit to the number (not size!) of docker volumes one can attach to a container. The subject is hard to Google since, understandably, most people focus on disk size and not the number.

Answer (score 1):

Docker itself does not impose any limits.
From the post
[Disk size of a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751032/disk-size-of-a-docker-image):

> There is no limits on the number of volumes a container can have. It
> is recommended to map directories inside the container that will grow
> in size into volumes.

However, some cloud providers impose limits upon this number.
From the article
[Node-specific Volume Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-limits/):

> Cloud providers like Google, Amazon, and Microsoft typically have a
> limit on how many volumes can be attached to a Node. It is important
> for Kubernetes to respect those limits. Otherwise, Pods scheduled on a
> Node could get stuck waiting for volumes to attach.
>
> The Kubernetes scheduler has default limits on the number of volumes
> that can be attached to a Node:
>
> ```
> Cloud service                     Maximum volumes per Node
> Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)    39
> Google Persistent Disk              16
> Microsoft Azure Disk Storage        16
> ```

Comment: The first part of your answer is great, thanks for that. For the second part, though, I wonder if there isn't a confusion between docker volumes and virtual disks. I know EBS for instance has nothing to do with docker. That said, it would be very nice to know if cloud vendors have their own limits, for services such as ECS or AWS Batch.